# $0^\#$ in weak theories vs large cardinals in $L$

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, large-cardinals, proof-theory, reverse-math

To better understand the transition from large cardinal axioms consistent with the constructible universe $L$ to large cardinal axioms transcending $L$, I am looking for natural equiconsistencies between "strong large cardinal in $L$" and "weak set theory + $0^\#$ exists".  As a result, I formed the following question/conjecture, but *other such equiconsistencies would also work as an answer*.

**Question:**  Is $\mathrm{ATR}_0$ + $Π^1_1$ transfinite induction + "$0^\#$ exists" equiconsistent with ZFC + {there is a virtually $n$-Ramsey cardinal}$_{n∈ℕ}$?

Here (i.e. for the purpose of this question), an infinite cardinal $κ$ is $n$-Ramsey if for every $f:κ^{<ω}→\{0,1\}$, there is $s$ homogeneous for $f$ such that $κ∈h^n(s∪\{κ\})$ where $h(x)=\{α∈x: \mathrm{ordertype}(x∩α)=α\}$.  'virtually' means that $s$ need only exist in a generic extension of $V$.

$\mathrm{ATR}_0$ is a commonly used subsystem of second order arithmetic consisting of basic axioms, induction for sets, and the ability to iterate arithmetic comprehension along a well-ordering. Over $\mathrm{RCA}_0$ (a weak base theory), it is equivalent to a variety of propositions, including open determinacy, clopen determinacy, analytic perfect subset property, $Σ^1_1$ separation, comparability of well-orderings, and so on.

The real number $0^\#$ (zero sharp) is the theory of finite tuples of Silver indiscernibles for $L$.  We can formalize it in $\mathrm{ATR}_0$ + $Π^1_1$ transfinite induction as follows: $0^\#$ is a complete theory satisfying certain basic axioms such that for every ordinal $α$, the Skolem hull using $α$ indiscernibles is well-founded.
We have:
* "$0^\#$ exists" is a $Σ^1_3$ statement; the above Skolem hull coded as a real number is computable from $0^\#$ and a real number coding $α$.
* $0^\#$ is unique: $\mathrm{ATR}_0$ gives uniqueness of $L$, and given two real numbers leading to closed classes of indiscernibles $I$ and $J$, using induction we can iterate $α→I_{J_α}$ to get a common set of indiscernibles.
* The [proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinacy#Proof_of_determinacy_from_sharps) of $Σ^1_1$ determinacy (accessed Jan 25, 2020) goes through in this setting (even without $Π^1_1$ transfinite induction); I do not know whether the reversal holds.
* KP + "$0^\#$ exist" with transfinite induction restricted to $Σ_1$ formulas appears to have the same strength (with well-foundedness of the Skolem hull interpreted through existence of the transitive collapse); however, the proof of $Σ^1_1$ determinacy does not appear to go through there.

For every $n∈ℕ$, in $\mathrm{ATR}_0$ + $Π^1_1$ transfinite induction + "$0^\#$ exists", each Silver indiscernible is, in $L$, totally indescribable, completely ineffable, and virtually $n$-Ramsey.  To prove the Ramseyness, one uses $Π^1_1$ transfinite induction to get an indiscernible with enough indiscernibles leading to it, which for $f∈L$ will give a homogeneous set in $V$.  Now, given $f$ and a real number coding $L_κ$, existence of a desired homogeneous set is $Σ^1_1$, so it also exists $L[G]$ if $G$ is generic for $\mathrm{Coll}(ω,κ)$ (note that $L[G]$ is closed under hyperjumps).

*Stronger theories:* Adding more induction gives stronger forms of Ramseyness, and $Π^1_1-\mathrm{CA}_0$ + "$0^\#$ exists", through existence of the hyperjump of $0^\#$ (and $Σ^1_2$ correctness of $L$ here), implies homogeneous sets with (within limits) any desired amount of diagonalization.

*Weaker theories:* $Π^1_1$ transfinite induction is important since in $\mathrm{ATR}_0$ without extra induction, the above definition of $0^\#$ can be split into existence of a set $M$ with basic properties of $0^\#$ such that every constructible set is inside a well-founded iterate of $M$ (let us call it weak $0^\#$ here) and a transfinite induction instance guaranteeing that for all $α∈\mathrm{Ord}$, $α$th iterate of $M$ is well-founded; and for both the weak and the strong version, we appear to need some induction (ordinary $Σ^1_1$ (equivalently, $Π^1_1$) induction suffices) to guarantee uniqueness of $0^\#$.  Here are some conjectured correspondences for provable $Σ_2^L$ statements (and if proved, potential answers):
$\mathrm{ATR}_0$ + weak $0^\#$ — ZFC + {there is $n$-iterable cardinal}$_{n∈ℕ}$
$\mathrm{ATR}_0$ + weak $0^\#$ + $Σ^1_1$ induction — ZFC + {there is $ω^n$-Erdos cardinal}$_{n∈ℕ}$ 
$\mathrm{ATR}_0$ + weak $0^\#$ + full induction (on $ω$) — ZFC + {there is $α$-Erdos cardinal}$_{α<ε_0}$
$\mathrm{ATR}_0$ + strong $0^\#$ implies that Silver indiscernibles are virtually almost Ramsey in $L$ and more; I conjecture correspondence with ZFC + (schema over $n$) $∃κ∈\mathrm{Ord} \, ∀f:κ^{<ω}→\{0,1\}$ "there is $s$ in a generic extension of $V$ with $s$ homogeneous for $f$ such that $s^n(0)$ exists", where $s(α)$ is the $(1+α)$th element of $s$.

*The trace of large cardinal axioms in *L*:*  As an aside, related to their relativization to $L$, virtual large cardinal axioms (even virtual rank-into-rank) tend to be weaker than $0^\#$.  However, we can define analogs of transitive models to get the trace of strong large cardinal axioms in $L$.  For example, ZFC + measurable cardinal proves the same $Σ^L_2$ statements as ZFC (or ZFC + $V=L$) augmented with (schema, $T$ is a finite fragment of ZFC + measurable):  There is a generic extension of $V$ with a transitive model $M$ of $T$ such that every $M$-cardinal is an $L$-cardinal in $V$.  More generally, this also works for $Σ^L_{n+1}$ statements using $\{α: L_α ≺_{Σ_n} L\}$ in place of $L$ cardinals, and also for $Π^L_{n+2}$ statements if, in addition, by varying the extension, the height of $M$ can be arbitrarily large.

Comment: This isn't quite what you're looking for, and doesn't answer your specific question, but you may be interested to look at the following paper if you haven't already: Cheng and Schindler, *Harrington's principle over higher order arithmetic* (https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.04000)

Comment: @DmytroTaranovsky Great and well-researched question! Unfortunately I don't know how to construct a model with a virtually Ramsey cardinal from $0^\#$.  Let me comment, what could be done in the other direction, i.e. with regard to the reduction of a weak base theory enhanced with $0^\#$ to $\mathsf{ZFC}+\{\text{"there is virtually n-Ramsey cardinal"\mid n\in \mathbb{N}\}$. By "reduction" I mean some apropritate partial conservation result.

Comment: @DmytroTaranovsky A weak base theories for which this works well are weak $\Pi_2$-axiomatizable set theories. For example a theory $\mathsf{BST}$ that is Extensionality + Regularity + Infinity + Axioms of Rudimentary Closure. In this setting $0^\#$ is defined to be a set of naturals (encoding a complete extension of $\mathsf{ZFC}+V=L$ with indecernibles) such that for any ordinal $\alpha$ the model with $\alpha$-many indecernibles generated from $0^\#$ is isomorphic to a transitive model (I will not be concerned with uniqueness).

Comment: @DmytroTaranovsky The theory $\mathsf{BST}+\text{"$0^\#$ exists"}$ could be easily reduced  to the theory $\mathsf{BST}+$ {there is  a complete extension $X$ of $\mathsf{ZFC}+V=L$ with indecernibles and ordinals $\alpha_0<\alpha_1<\ldots<\alpha_{n}$ such that model with $\alpha_i$-many indecernibles generated from $X$ is isomorphic to $L_{\alpha_{i+1}}$ | $n\in \mathbb{N}$}. The latter theory in turn could be easily reduced to $\mathsf{ZFC}+\{\text{there is a virtually $n$-Ramsey cardinal} \mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$.

Comment: @DmytroTaranovsky However, $\mathsf{ATR}_0^{\mathsf{set}}$ (which is the direct set-theoretic counterpart of $\mathsf{ATR}_0$) contains Axiom Beta, which might be problematic for the mentioned reductions.

Comment: @FedorPakhomov With respect to strength using $0^\#$, ATR$_0$ without extra induction is likely similar to BST.  However, using Axiom Beta (or for KP, bounded collection), we appear to have a hierarchy with a four-way correspondence: more induction $⇔$ more diagonalization of indiscernibles $⇔$ stronger partition properties in $L$ $⇔$ (at some points) fuller meaningfulness of $0^\#$.